# C++11 - constructor inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I am not a C++ expert, so I need a help with perhaps a basic concept of C++ programming.

I have two classes, where one inherit from the other, so

```
class SuperClass
{
   private:
      std::string name;
      std::string str;
      long value;

   public: 
      SuperClass(std::string, std::string, long);
      ~SuperClass(void);
}

class SubClass : public SuperClass
{
   public: 
      SubClass(std::string, std::string, long);
      ~SubClass(void);
}
```

Now, in the main function, I would like to use `SubClass` objects, so I will need to initialize variables of `SuperClass` object. but with this code:

```
SubClass::SubClass(string name, string str, long value) : SuperClass(name, 
str, value)
{
   ;
}
```

gcc returns the error:

```
multiple definition of `SubClass::SubClass(std::string, std::string, long)'
```

So, what it the correct way to call a super-class constructor from a derived class in C++11 ?

Comment: At first, you probably want `class SubClass : public SuperClass` for inheritance.

Comment: Yes it is an error of rewriting an example of my problem. Sorry

Comment: Can you please post the full, compilable, code example that leads to the error?

Comment: *'multiple definition'* means there are several definition, so in several cpp file or not marked `inline` if definition is placed in header.

Comment: Also, your classes are missing `;` at the end of their definitions, that can cause a variety of error messages

Comment: What you are doing is fine, your *multiple definitions* may come from putting the constructor definition in the heeder file?

Comment: Oh Yes, In my original source code I have two derived classes and I was calling the constructor on one derived class in both derived classes .cc files. : S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct (by the way the empty statement in the constructor body `;` is not necessary) but you can only *define* that constructor in exactly one compilation unit (unless you put the whole thing inside the class declaration).

The simplest thing for you to do is to put the definition in a source file.

Note that the class will **not** be a polymorphic type unless at least one `virtual` function is present in your base class.  "Virtualising" the destructor by writing `virtual ~SuperClass() = default;` is the simplest thing to do.

You might find that your omitting the compulsory `;` at the end of each class declaration is simply confusing the compiler.

Comment: You have an extra `=` in declaration of virtual destructor.